Radius of convergence of complex power series
Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n $ is convergent at $i$. Then its radius of convergent $R$ is $\geq 1$. Is it correct? If so, can someone please explain how? Thanks a lot.

Have you tried anything?

Yes, I think from definition it follows. But I am not convinced.

Proof is by comparison with a geometric series.

Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

It is as simple as it gets, it can't be made any simpler. If $R$ were $<1$, then the series would diverge at every $z$ with $|z|=1$, and in particular, at $i$.

Thanks a lot. @
